# Tangent space of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ at I

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Working thorugh the exercises in Thorpe's book "Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry" I've got stuck on the last step of this one:

> Prove that tangent space of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ at $I=\begin{pmatrix}1
>  & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is the set of all matrices of trace zero.

Following the hints I get that if

$$\alpha(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x_1(t) & x_2(t)  \\ x_3(t) & x_4(t) \end{pmatrix}$$

is a parametrized curve in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\alpha(t_0)=\begin{pmatrix}x_1(t_0) & x_2(t_0)  \\ x_3(t_0) & x_4(t_0) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1
 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then $(dx_1/dt)(t_0)+(dx_4/dt)(t_0)=0$.

This is true because since $\alpha(t)\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $x_1(t)x_4(t)-x_2(t)x_3(t)=1$. Derivating respect to $t$ and evaluating at $t_0$:

$$\frac{dx_1(t_0)}{dt}x_4(t_0)+x_1(t_0)\frac{dx_4(t_0)}{dt}=\frac{dx_1(t_0)}{dt}\cdot 1+1 \cdot\frac{dx_4(t_0)}{dt}=0$$

Now for the last step it says: **"Then use a dimensional argument"** I'm not sure how to proceed.

> Can someone help me complete the proof? Of course, any comment if I'm wrong with the argument above is welcomed.

Comment: So you've shown everything in the tangent space has zero trace.  What's the dimension of the space of 2x2 matrices with zero trace?  What's the dimension of the tangent space of SL_2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$SL_2(\mathbb R) = \{ A : \det A = 1\}$$

is a three dimensional manifold. Thus it's tangent space is also three dimensional. You've shown that

$$T =  \{ X : \text{tr} X = 0\}$$

lies in the tangent space of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ at $I$. Since $T$ is also three dimensional, it must be that $T = T_I SL_2(\mathbb R)$.